# VBA Project creating a subroutine

Tags: vba, input, subroutine, inputbox

I have the following task:

"Create a subroutine called WherePutMe that asks the user for a row number and column letter then places the 2,2 position of a selection into that cell.

So far I did

```
Sub Whereputme()
  Dim x as integer, y as string
  x= Inputbox ("Enter a row number")
  y= Inputbox ("Enter a column letter")
  z= selection.range("B2")
End Sub
```

There is still something missing..how can I link the inputbox inputs with z?

Comment: Can you explain "places the 2,2 position of a selection into that cell"?

Comment: the question needs more clarification of what a "cell" refers to and what is included in 2,2 position? it will be helpful to as a snippet also show what the output should look like.

Answer (score 2):

You have `End Sub`, but no `Sub` statement.. is this the whole code? What if the user cancels the prompts?

Assuming you're in a standard module (e.g. `Module1.bas`), you'll want it to have `Option Explicit` at the top, and then the `Sub` statement defines the procedure you need to implement - consider making it explicitly `Public`, too:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WherePutMe()
    'TODO
End Sub
```

That said "Where put me" is a horrible name for a procedure. Best practice is to use meaningful names that convey the purpose of the code - and since procedures *do something*, you'll want their names to generally start with a verb.

Unqualified, `InputBox` is invoking `VBA.Interaction.InputBox`, a VBA standard library function that prompts the user for a string, and the user can <kbd>Cancel</kbd> out of that prompt. When this happens, what you get is a null string pointer that implicitly converts to an empty string - but then, the user could very well enter an empty string and hit <kbd>Ok</kbd>, so before we validate the input we first need to know how the prompt was dismissed.

This quickly gets complicated and chaotic. We could abstract this complexity behind a function:

```
Private Function TryGetUserInput(ByVal prompt As String, ByRef result As String) As Boolean
    result = InputBox(prompt)
    TryGetUserInput = (StrPtr(result) <> 0)
End Function
```

And now we can do this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WherePutMe()
    Dim userRowInput As String, userRow As Long, isValid As Boolean
    Do While Not isValid
        If TryGetUserInput("Enter a row number", userRowInput) Then
            'user submitted a value, now validate it
            If IsNumeric(userRowInput) Then
                'looks legit
                userRow = CLng(userRowInput)
                '...but is it?
                isValid = userRow > 0
            End If
        Else
            'user cancelled the prompt
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Not isValid Then MsgBox "Invalid row number. Please enter a positive integer between 1 and 1,048,576.", vbExclamation
    Loop
    'TODO: get and validate the column letter
End Sub
```

Avoid code that makes too many assumptions (broken assumption => bug; think of how any given instruction might possibly fail and throw an error that sends everything up in flames), and don't hesitate to break things down into small, specialized procedures and functions - like the above loop would look pretty neat in its own `TryGetValidRowNumber` function that returns `False` if the user cancelled out, `True` otherwise, with a `ByRef` output parameter holding a `Long` integer value that the caller could use directly:

```
Public Sub WherePutMe()
    Dim rowNumber As Long
    If Not TryGetValidRowNumber(rowNumber) Then Exit Sub

    Dim columnLetter As String
    If Not TryGetValidColumnLetter(columnLetter) Then Exit Sub

    Dim targetCell As Range
    Set targetCell = ActiveSheet.Range(columnLetter & rowNumber)

    'TODO consume the targetCell as needed
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is you are defining `z` as something but you are not using it.

By simply removing the `z =` portion of you code, you are now telling VBA that you want something to happen, not wanting to define a variable.

You may want to do something along the lines of the following where [`CStr`](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/convert-number-to-string/) converts the number into a string in case that ever becomes an issue when combining a string and an integer together.

```
Sub Whereputme()
  Dim x As Integer, y As String
  x = InputBox("Enter a row number")
  y = InputBox("Enter a column letter")
  Cells(2, 2).Value = y & CStr(x)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx for the explanation..since I am a beginner..still lot to learn

Comment: No problem. This helped?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub WherePutMe()
    Dim x As Integer, y As String, z As String
    Dim str As String

    x = InputBox("Enter a row number")
    y = InputBox("Enter a column letter")
    z = Selection.Range("B2")
    str = y & x

    ActiveSheet.Range(str) = z

End Sub
```

Comment: Code-only answers may solve the problem but they are much more useful if you explain how they solve it. Community requires theory as well as code both to understand your answer fully.